# Why is overlapping groups in group lasso more complicated?

Tags: lasso

I read that overlapping group lasso is more complicated compared to non overlapping group lasso with respect to optimization (section 3, paragraph 2 page 11 https://arxiv.org/pdf/1701.08140.pdf).

Can someone explain why this is the case optimization-wise, and what the other problems are (not just w.r.t. optimization) for overlapping group lasso compared to non overlapping group lasso?